# Specific weigthlifting protocol to strengthen tendons, regardless of hypertrophy or any other goal

Tags: weightlifting, strength-training, tendons

This question was indirectly embedded within other more general questions I made in this site, for example [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/on-the-influence-of-the-total-number-of-sets-particularly-with-regard-to-tendon) and [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13522/how-can-i-achieve-healthy-tendons-and-balanced-muscles-with-no-particular-hurry). But the scope was more general. I would like to do this specific question here now, mainly because I have found very interesting information that can be useful to another readers, so I will answer it by myself. Please note that I will not elect my own answer as the best one: you are encouraged to post your own answers and relevant information on the question too.

This all has happened because I started training at middle age with very poor conditioning. In only a month and a half, I managed to see my muscles bulking in the mirror and I was enthusiastic, but I had to stop and it is months now that I am healing a lot of different tendinosis. Which shows that, at middle age, your skeletal muscles might feel as young as ever, but your tendons play in a different league and a different approach is needed. So, my question:

Regardless of muscular hypertrophy or endurance or whatever your goal, what is a specific way of weightlifting specifically directed towards strengthening your tendons?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but I have been in your specific situation (tendinosis everywhere), and it turned out to be just angry trigger points. I solved about 90% of my problems by finding a trigger point massage therapist.

Answer (score 3):

What my new therapist uses to prescribe in order to help healing not very severe tendon problems is **slow eccentric exercises**, aka **negative phases**, with *very light* weights, two or three sets, three times a day, everyday.

Now, I think that you don't need to be a rocket scientist to understand that, whatever is useful to heal and strengthen an injured tendon, is likely to be helpful in strengthening a healthy tendon as well.

Here are some links to places where I have seen sort of confirmation to this question, and references to scientific papers:

This [link, tendinosis.org](http://tendinosis.org/current.shtml) with this paragraph, among other interesting data:

> Studies have shown that loading a tendon parallel to its length helps
>   the collagen fibers grow with better parallel alignment and speeds the
>   healing process. (...)
>
> Some studies have shown that eccentric exercise is especially helpful
>   for tendinosis. [50, 51, 52, 53, 54] Eccentric exercise is when a
>   muscle is forced to lengthen while it contracts because it is being
>   used as a brake or to absorb energy while doing "negative work."

This other post in T-Nation, [Accentuated Eccentric Training](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance/accentuated_eccentric_training) says:

> Eccentric training is also a superior method to treat tendinitis when
>   compared with concentric exercise (Mafi et al. 2001). It could be
>   argued that this form of training is beneficial to injured athletes
>   and that it's relatively safer than concentric training even if the
>   loads used are greater.

But the best one on this question of tendons and tendonitis is [this one](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance/eccentric_exercise_a_solution_to_tendonitis) (in T-nation too):

> Surfing the web one day, I came across a posting on a newsgroup that
>   described a study done on runners with long-term, chronic Achilles
>   tendonitis. The study involved a new treatment that achieved
>   remarkable results in only 12 weeks. (...) The study, done in Sweden,
>   used two groups of fifteen middle-aged ex-runners who couldn't run due
>   to chronic Achilles tendonitis. (...) The special exercise program
>   involved performing calf raises with the legs both straight and
>   slightly bent twice a day, seven days a week for three sets of 15
>   repetitions (to hit both the gastros and soleus). The subjects
>   performed the concentric part of the exercise (raising the heel) with
>   the uninjured ankle and used the injured side to do the eccentric
>   lowering phase in a slow, controlled fashion. (...) At the end of the
>   twelve-week period, all the patients in the exercise group had
>   returned to running at their pre-injury level. (...) In a recent
>   two-year follow up of the fifteen runners in the exercise group,
>   fourteen were still running pain free(...)

Judge by yourself.

Comment: Supporting evidence: http://www.reddit.com/r/weightroom/comments/1sdl08/is_it_possible_to_train_specifically_tendons_in/cdymc10